# Can we say "put the lid on the box" and "take the lid off the box" when one side of the lid is joined to the box?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

We can say "**slide the lid open / closed**" as shown in the above picture

Or

[image]

We can say "**snap/click the lid open / closed**" as shown in the above picture

But what about this one

[image]

Note that one side of the lid is joined to the box so we can only move the lid freely into "**on-off**" position. And, I am not sure we can "**take it off**" and "**put it on**".

Can we say "**move the lid open / closed**" in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That hinged part is the lid. I'd understand "Take the lid off". (Even though it could mean "cut it off with sissors")

However, the simple expression is "Open the box"/"Close the box".  No need to mention lids at all.

You could say "lift the lid" if using the word lid is important.

Comment: I would also consider calling it a "top" when it's joined like that, but not to the exclusion of "lid".

Answer (score 0):

Shut the lid. Open the lid. Flip it open, close the lid.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/141632)